# attempt to index a nil value on FiveM esx_policejob

Tags: lua, fivem

attempt to index a nil value (local 'weapon')
In the first line is the error

```
local component = weapon.components[i]
local hasComponent = HasPedGotWeaponComponent(playerPed, GetHashKey(v.weapon), component.hash)

if hasComponent then
    label = ('%s: <span style="color:green;">%s</span>'):format(component.label, _U('armory_owned'))
else
    if v.components[i] > 0 then
        label = ('%s: <span style="color:green;">%s</span>'):format(component.label, _U('armory_item', ESX.Math.GroupDigits(v.components[i])))
    else
        label = ('%s: <span style="color:green;">%s</span>'):format(component.label, _U('armory_free'))
    end
end
```

[image: 1]

Comment: well weapon is a nil value. you cannot index nil values. so find out why it is nil. we can't do that for you

Answer (score -1):

I am not completely sure if this works out, but that would be my solution:

Check if you have this in your script!

`ESX=nil`

if not write it at the top!

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward, `weapon` is nil. Changing `ESX` would have no impact on `weapon`.